# how can I synchronize one file with git in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, gitlab

I work in a team project and we are using git.
I have a simple question.
I have made some changes in one file. 
How can I delete these changes and synchronize it with the remote repository(where the correct code is saved)

Thank you and BR,
Kostas

Comment: Perhaps you mean `git reset`,  then `git pull`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to synchronise your local repository with the one in GitLab you need to do:

```
git checkout filename
git pull
```

If you want to discard temporarily your changes in order to synchronise and then re-appliying them you can do:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
```

and continue working.